# Prove that the number of $k$-simplexes in an $n$-orthoplex is $2^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}$ (where $n,k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $0 \leqslant k < n$)?

Tags: combinatorics, finite-groups, combinatorial-geometry, polytopes

In the book 'Regular Polytopes' (H.S.M. Coxeter, 1973), Coxeter describes the  $n$-orthoplex (which I will refer to from now on as $\beta_{n}$, and is the $n$-dimensional analogue of the octahedron) as the dipyramid with base $\beta_{n-1}$. This description leads to the following equation (Where $N_{k}^{n}$ denotes the number of $k$-simplexes which are elements of $\beta_{n}$)

$$N_{k}^{n}=N_{k}^{n-1} + 2N_{k-1}^{n-1}$$

We have further that $N_{0}^{n} = 2n = 2^{1}\binom{n}{1} \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.

The author then states the result in the title follows easily by induction, however I am not sure exactly how. Could anyone possibly help?

Comment: We will proceed by induction on $k$. Suppose that
$$N_{l}^{k}=2^{l+1}\binom{n}{l+1} \quad \forall \quad 0 \leqslant l <k<n$$
\begin{align*}
N_{k}^{n} & = N_{k}^{n-1} + 2N_{k-1}^{n-1} \\
& = N_{k}^{n-1} + 2^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}\\
& = N_{k}^{n-2} + 2^{k+1}\binom{n-2}{k} + 2^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k} \\
& = .\dots \\
& = N_{k}^{k} + 2^{k+1}\binom{k}{k} + \dots + 2^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}\\
& = 2^{k+1}\sum_{i=k}^{n-1}\binom{i}{k} & \text{since } N_{k}^{k} = 0\\
& = 2^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1} & \text{using the fact} \sum_{i=a}^{b}\binom{i}{a} = \binom{b+1}{a+1} \\
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty easy direct argument. The $n$ orthoplex has $n$ pairs of vertices $v_i^{\pm}$ for $i=1,\ldots n,$ and a subset of the vertices represents a face iff it does not contain both a vertex $v^+_i$ and its opposite $v^-_i$. This is easy to see by how the orthoplexes are inductively constructed.

Now a $k$ simplex has $k+1$ vertices, and since it can't contain both vertices in a pair, we must first choose $k+1$ indices which yields $\binom{n}{k+1}$ choices, and then choose on vertex from each pair, which is another $2^{k+1}$ choices.

Comment: Thank you :), that argument is much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the given identity, apply the induction hypothesis, factor out $2^{k+1}$, then apply Pascal's rule.
\begin{align}
N^n_k
&= N^{n-1}_k+2N^{n-1}_{k-1}
\\&=2^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k+1}+2\cdot 2^{(k-1)+1}\binom{n-1}{(k-1)+1}
\\&=2^{k+1}\left[\binom{n-1}{k+1}+\binom{n-1}k\right]
\\&=2^{k+1}\binom{n}{k+1}.
\end{align}